# What does 'W/DIO' mean when used for MOSFET descriptions?

Tags: mosfet, terminology

For example on Farnell: [VISHAY SILICONIX SIHP18N50C-E3 MOSFET,N CH,W DIO,500V,18A,TO220AB](http://uk.farnell.com/vishay-siliconix/sihp18n50c-e3/mosfet-n-ch-w-dio-500v-18a-to220ab/dp/1869883)

I've googled it in various forms but all it returns is other listings for MOSFETs with that in the title.

I also checked through a load of data sheets but couldn't see what it was referring to.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be a description that Farnell generated. The description for that part at Digikey, for example, is just "MOSFET N-CH 500V 18A TO220", and at Mouser it's "MOSFET 560V 18A 223W 270mohm @ 10V".

I can only speculate about what Farnell intended, but maybe they meant "with diode". This is kind of a silly thing to add to the description, because this part doesn't have any integrated diode except for the body diode that all MOSFETs have between drain and source.

The part's datasheet does contain some characteristic specs for the properties of the body diode, which might make it useful in some applications where you're actually going to use the body diode to carry current.

It might make sense to describe a MOSFET as "with diode" if it had, for example, an integrated ESD protection diode between gate and source.

Comment: I think you are right, about 90% of the google results for "W/DIO mosfet" are just from Farnell, Newark etc. Not really other sites. So maybe it is just a mistake on their part.

Comment: There are MOSFETs co-packaged with Schottky diodes in parallel with the intrinsic body diode, such as [this](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/sic/mosfet/sch2080ke.pdf) one. Maybe some intern got confused by the schematic symbols and classified them wrong. It happens at all the distributors.